# HTML5 Canvas.. Works in firefox, weird in internet explorer 10?

Tags: html

I'm using the Canvas to draw 2D objects, and clearing them/redrawing rectangles. In firefox everything works well and the rendering is great. However, in internet explorer 10 things are in the wrong position and the graphics are flickering. Why is this/

Comment: two words: internet explorer

Comment: please post your HTML source to see what might be the problem

Comment: If you could provide your HTML source code this will help us find out the issue